# DIRAC2 for real time pitch shifting and autotune?

Tags: iphone, audiounit, pitch, pitch-shifting

Has anyone implemented the DIRAC2 library from http://www.dspdimension.com/technology-licensing/dirac2-iphone/ for real time pitch correction on the iPhone? The library doesn't appear to support real time processing but perhaps someone has done it?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed from DSP Dimensions, that the current DIRAC2 library will not work in real time.

Answer (score 1):

I integrated DIRAC2 into an iPhone app so I could modify the playback speed, and it does indeed work in real-time on an iPhone 4.  I had to use the lowest possible settings to keep the CPU usage down, but it does play without any skips and I am able to change the playback speed seamlessly.

Running the same project on a 3GS device yielded lesser results - namely that the audio had enough skipping that it wasn't really usable.  One caveat to this, though, is that I was running my test on the free version of DIRAC2 which only supports a 44100 sample rate, which is much higher than I need.  If the pro version is used and you slash the sample rate down to 22050 or lower, it might work on a 3GS, but don't quote me on that.

Anything older than a 3GS has absolutely no chance of real-time playback.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Playback speed is significantly different than pitch correction. It can also be done without DIRAC2 with acceptable results. The technique isn't that tricky and I still don't believe it works. I will write it up eventually.

Comment: My real-time playback using DIRAC2 does automatic pitch correction, and it works fine as per my post above.  DIRAC3 came out recently which is supposed to be even more CPU efficient, though I haven't used it yet.